# How is it possible to get AUC = 0.72, but sensitivity = 0?

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting, roc, confusion-matrix

I've trained a Gradient Boost classifier and used it to predict a binary target variable. I plot the ROC, here it is, looks nice and good:

[image]

###### However, using the same test data, this is the result of a confusion matrix:

[image]

###### How could this happen? the model fails to predict positive cases, the sensitivity is zero, but still the ROC curve doesn't show zero in the y-axis..! here is the code I used, notice that I used the same data (in R):

```
### For the ROC and AUC assessments

gbmROC_tst = roc(tst1$CR,predict(ML_Model,tst1, type='prob')[,1])
plot(gbmROC_tst, main = 'Test set - GBM model')
auc(gbmROC_tst)

### For the confusion matrix

y_pred1 = predict(ML_Model, tst1) %>% as.factor()
y_real1 = tst1$CR %>% as.factor()
caret::confusionMatrix(data = y_real1, reference =  y_pred1, dnn = c('Truth','Predictions'))
```

###### And finally, this is a subset of tst1, which is the test set of my data:

```
> dput(tst1[1:15,1:15])

structure(list(CR = c("nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", 
"nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", 
"nonComplete", "nonComplete", "Complete", "nonComplete", "Complete", 
"Complete", "Complete"), gender = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), cancer_type_Breast = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cancer_type_Colorectal = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cancer_type_Melanoma = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), cancer_type_NSCLC = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `cancer_type_Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), cancer_type_Sarcoma = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `cancer_type_Thymic Carcinoma` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `cancer_type_Urothelial Bladder Carcinoma` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Treatment_anti-CTLA4` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Treatment_anti-PD1` = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `Treatment_anti-PD1 + anti-CTLA4` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Treatment_anti-PDL1` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), age = c(-0.214955076106036, 
0.0131727344688938, -0.329018981393501, -0.443082886680966, -0.214955076106036, 
0.0131727344688938, -0.899338507830825, -1.01340241311829, -1.46965803426815, 
-0.214955076106036, 0.811620071481148, -3.40874442415505, 0.469428355618753, 
0.127236639756359, 1.15381178734354)), row.names = c("Pt2", "Pt24", 
"Pt29", "Pt34", "Pt49", "Pt5", "Pt78", "Pt8", "Pt82", "Pt89", 
"Pt94", "EA595529", "EA595597", "EA595647", "EA595654"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you have imbalanced classes? // Could you please post a picture of your output probabilities. Best would be superimposed histograms or kernel density plots. A pokey culprit of this behavior is that the default threshold of $0.5$ never gets exceeded but that you have decent separation between classes on lower probabilities.

Comment: That confusion matrix corresponds to a sensitivity of $0$ and a specificity of $1$, which is the point on the ROC in the bottom left.  Presumably with different thresholds for prediction you would get other points on the curve

Answer (score 2):

This is totally reasonable behavior. Remember that the ROC curve looks at all possible thresholds for making classifications. However, the default threshold in every software I know for making a classification is an output probability of $0.5$.

Especially if you have class imbalance, it is possible that your model always predicts probabilities below this threshold. However, you still could have decent separation between the classes below that threshold, resulting in zero sensitivity to detect a class with a threshold of $0.5$ yet still $AUC=0.72$.